# C++ Aligning CSV Files based on peaks of data

Tags: c++, csv

I currently have two or more csv files with 20 columns in each, and a different number of rows, which have (integer) waveform data, however the files are not in sync with one another. (varying number of lines, 20 individual pieces of data in each line)

I am trying to use the first 8 columns of each csv file, and find the first peak of data in one of the respective columns of each file, then align the respective columns of data with one another (if you align one set with one another the rest will also be in line, because all of the data in each line of each file was taken at the same time). One the data is aligned, I want to send it all into a new csv file with 16 columns (8 for each file, 16 total).

So far I have thought of trying to take each csv file in, split it based on commas into their own respective vectors (because I do not have the initial length of each file, otherwise I would initialize a set of arrays, or an object) then find the index of the first max peaks of two respective columns from the separate files, and buffer whichever one is shorter than the other in order to align the peaks with one another.
This is also supposed to be dynamic in the sense of it can be used to compare multiple files at once, not just two.

I have also considered taking in the csv files into objects to be able to call each column of data easily, as I should be using classes somewhere throughout the task.

I am having difficulty trying to figure out what might be the most effective method, if anyone has an idea please share! If there are any other questions I could answer to possibly clarify anything please let me know!

Comment: There are many details about your situation that are not present in your question. For example, while it seems reasonable to infer that your data consists of numbers (based upon going "up and down", that is not guaranteed by the information presented (text can also increase then decrease). I suspect that if someone were to propose an answer, your reply would be that the proposal will not work because of information you neglected to provide.

Comment: You probably should look at your situation more abstractly, break the task into smaller pieces, and focus on one piece at a time. For example, does the fact that the data comes in a CSV format really matter to the processing? You have tabular data, with 20 columns and an arbitrary number of rows. One task is to convert that data to a usable form (from CSV). Another task is to work with that data. Don't try to do both at once. When working with the data, abstract away its origin.

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you for pointing that out, I made the correction regarding the type of data, it is primarily integers in the columns besides the first and second which are timestamps. At the moment I have looked at it in a step by step view, with how to take in the data, but looking forward on if I take it in a certain way, can it be changed or moved around in the future easily.

Comment: It sounds like the CSV files contain waveform (-like) sample data and you're looking to shift the data in order to cross-correlate the waveforms across the files?

As others have said, some more detail about the fundamental problem you're trying to solve would be useful.

Comment: @Modest *"I have looked at [...] how to take in the data, but looking forward on if I take it in a certain way, can it be changed or moved around in the future easily."* -- you're almost there. You realize that you want a format that will be convenient for future analysis. Next, should come the realization that reading the data will require some conversion anyway, so shift from thinking *"how to read; don't hamper future analysis"* to thinking *"how to analyze; don't overburden reading"*. Design your data structure based on its use rather than its origin.

Comment: @Den-Jason, I had a mental slip when thinking of how to describe the data, yes it is waveform data - I apologize for not having been clearer on that. I am trying to align it based on the first peak of one of the waveforms. If there is anything specific I could clarify please let me know!

Comment: @JaMiT Ah so you're saying stick with the small problems first, figure out how to take all the data in, once I have that I should move forward on how to handle the data. Thank you for guiding, sometimes its helpful just to have someone else's input to put you on the right direction, or give you the motivation to move forward .

Comment: What counts as a peak for your application?

Comment: Also, do you want to synchronize by peak? Or is this just one option for synchronizing your waveforms?

Comment: @Riley max value/ point of the first peak would be what I want to synchronize on. Align the other file's respective peak with this one. An example would be that both files have x,y,z wave forms polled at the same instance, so synchronize the peak of the x's, and do the same buffering or whatever of the data to y, and z, then the files should be in alignment I assume?

Comment: If there's significant error or noise in your data this may not be robust. But it's definitely worth trying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237762/discussion-between-riley-and-modest).

Comment: Please check the below answer. Please inform, if I understood you somehow correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say, but even reading your statements and all comments, it is still not that clear, what you want to do. Sorry for that.

It would have been helpfull to see the input format and the expected output.

Anyway, I will try to help.

There are several problems mentioned. And we will split down the big problems into many small problems, with many classes and methods. That is then easierto solve.

Let's start with the basic waveform. We will create a class, containing 2 times stamps, all the values of the curve and then a dynamic `std::vector` with the peak value and the index of the peak value.

```
// Basic wave form
struct WaveForm {
    long timestamp1{};
    long timestamp2{};

    std::vector<int> values{};
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, int>> peaks{};

    // Input and output
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, WaveForm& wf);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const WaveForm& wf);

    // Find max peak values
    void findPeaks();
    // And shift the phase to left or right. Shift left will leadtoloss of data
    void shiftPhase(int delta);
};
```

The `findPeaks();` function will find all local maxpeaks of the curve. `shiftPhase` will shift the values of the curve to the left (by deleting trailing values) or to the right, by inserting "0" values.

The inserter will do a simple output of all data. And the extractor will read one line of comma separated value (CSV) and split that into the relevant parts. So, I repeat, this will work with ONE input line. It is important, that we encapsulate the reading and splitting into one function. Even, if the input format would be different, we just need to change this one function and the rest will continue to work.

Let us look at the input, the extractor function. First, we will read a complete line and then put this line into a `std::istringstream` for further easy extraction and conversion of values. So, we will extract the time stamps, and then, in a simple while loop, all values. All values that we read, will be pushed into our internal "values"-vector. So, rather straightforward and simple. Nothing complicated.

The output function (inserter) is even more simple.

Now, lets come to the max peak value search. The problem is often a discrete signal with overlayed noise. Let us look at the following example with a base sinusuid curve and some heavy noise:

[image]

We will add 2 thresholds. An upper and a lower one, or just an upper one but with a negative hysteris. Sounds complicated, but is not.

We will evaluate value by value and if we pass the upper threshold, we will start looking for a maximum. We will do this until we cross the lower threshold. At this moment, we will store the so far calculated max value (together with its index). Then, we wait until we cross again the upper threshold. The hysteresis will prevent continuos toggling of the search mode in case of noise.

With this mechanism, we can find all the max peaks easily. Please see:

```
// FInd local max peak values in a curve
void WaveForm::findPeaks() {

    // Definition of Threashold value and hysteresis to find max peak values
    constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageHigh{ 0.7 };
    constexpr double Hyteresis{ 0.2 };
    constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageLow{ ThreshholdPercentageHigh - Hyteresis };

    // First find the overall min / max to calculate some threshold data
    const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(values.cbegin(), values.cend());
    const int threasholdMaxHigh = static_cast<int>((*max - *min) * ThreshholdPercentageHigh + *min);
    const int threasholdMaxLow = static_cast<int>((*max - *min) * ThreshholdPercentageLow + *min);

    // Initiliaze with lowest possible value, so that any other value will be bigger
    int maxPeak{ std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    // Indexof the max peak value
    size_t maxPeakIndex{};

    // We need to kno, if the search is active
    // And we need toknow, when there is a transition from active to inactive
    bool searchActive{};
    bool oldSearchActive{};

    // Go through all values
    for (size_t index{}; index < values.size(); ++index) {

        // Check,if values are above threshold, then switch on search mode
        if (not searchActive) {
            if (values[index] > threasholdMaxHigh) 
                searchActive = true;
        }
        else {
            // Else, if value is lower than lower threshold, then switch of search mode formaxpeak
            if (values[index] < threasholdMaxLow) 
                searchActive = false;
        }
        // If the search is active, then find the max peak
        if (searchActive)
            if (values[index] > maxPeak) {
                maxPeak = values[index];
                maxPeakIndex = index;
            }
        // Check fora transition from active to inactive. In that very moment, store the previosuly found values
        if ((not searchActive and oldSearchActive) or (index == values.size()-1)) {
            peaks.push_back({ maxPeakIndex, maxPeak });
            maxPeak = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
            maxPeakIndex = 0;
        }
        // Rememberfor next round
        oldSearchActive = searchActive;
        searchActive = values[index] > threasholdMaxHigh;
    }
    return;
}
```

Next would be to read not only one line of values from the source file, but an arbitrary long file with many rows and with even different columns per row.

For this, we define the next class "WaveFormData", which holds a collection (`std::vector`) of wave data.

Extractor and inserter operator will be overwritten and call the above defined functions in a loop.

Please note. Already now, we can read a complete CSV file with any number of rows and any different number of columns for each row with a simple `>>` statement. So, if you have openen the file and have an ìnput file stream, you can simply write

```
    WaveFormData wfd{};
    fileStream >> wfd;
```

This will read the complete file and parse it. Very convenient.

So, then next will be the alignment. We will simply align on a previously calculated max value and then shift the phase of other curves that shall be aligned.

Shifting a phase to the right is simple. We can just add the requested number of 0s at the beginning of the values. Shifting left is a little bit more complicated, because we will lose leading values. In order to avoid losing values, we will calculate the most right position of a max value over all curves of one file. Then, we never need to shift left and do not lose any data.

```
// Over all waveforms in the collection, get right most first peak value
int WaveFormData::calculatPhaseDelta() {

    int rightMostPeakIndex{ std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    for (auto& wf : waveForms) {
        wf.findPeaks(); // Calculate the peaks
        if (not wf.peaks.empty())
            // Get first peak rightmost peak. So, the peak in a first cycle
            rightMostPeakIndex = std::max(rightMostPeakIndex, static_cast<int>(wf.peaks[0].first));
    }
    return rightMostPeakIndex;
}
```

Then, we can shift all curves regarding the calculated index.

```
// Shifts the phase to the left or right
void WaveForm::shiftPhase(int delta) {
    // Shift to right?
    if (delta > 0) {
        // insert 0-elements at the beginning
        values.insert(values.begin(), delta, 0);
    }
    else if (delta < 0) {
        //delete "delta" number of elements from the beginning
        values.erase(values.begin(), values.begin() - delta);
    }
    // Correct time stampps
    timestamp1 += delta;
    timestamp2 += delta;
}
```

And at the end, we can collect the data of 2 or more files in an additional class. I added an example for just 2 files. I added also a function to create test data.

If you want more, then use again a `std::vector` for that.

But the shown implementation will give you and idea on how to do.

I do not understand your requirments about the output.

But, because you have all data, you can simply add.

The complete program draft may look like the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <climits>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>

constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageHigh{ 0.7 };
constexpr double Hyteresis{ 0.2 };
constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageLow{ ThreshholdPercentageHigh - Hyteresis };
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Basic wave form
struct WaveForm {
    long timestamp1{};
    long timestamp2{};

    std::vector<int> values{};
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, int>> peaks{};

    // Input and output
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, WaveForm& wf);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const WaveForm& wf);

    // Find max peak values
    void findPeaks();
    // And shift the phase to left or right. Shift left will leadtoloss of data
    void shiftPhase(int delta);
};
// Read one line of csv data
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, WaveForm& wf) {

    // First read a complete line from the source stream
    if (std::string line{}; std::getline(is, line)) {

        // Put this into an istringstream for easier extraction
        std::istringstream iss{ line };
        // Initialize (local) variables
        char comma{}; int value; wf.values.clear();

        // Extract data
        iss >> wf.timestamp1 >> comma >> wf.timestamp2;
        while (iss >> comma >> value) 
            wf.values.push_back(value);
    }
    return is;
}
// Simply output all data in the vector in a selected format
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const WaveForm& wf) {
    os << std::setw(12) << wf.timestamp1 << ' ' << std::setw(12) << wf.timestamp2 << ' ';
    for (const int v : wf.values) os << std::setw(4) << v << ' ';
    return os;
}
// FInd local max peak values in a curve
void WaveForm::findPeaks() {

    // Definition of Threashold value and hysteresis to find max peak values
    constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageHigh{ 0.7 };
    constexpr double Hyteresis{ 0.2 };
    constexpr double ThreshholdPercentageLow{ ThreshholdPercentageHigh - Hyteresis };

    // First find the overall min / max to calculate some threshold data
    const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(values.cbegin(), values.cend());
    const int threasholdMaxHigh = static_cast<int>((*max - *min) * ThreshholdPercentageHigh + *min);
    const int threasholdMaxLow = static_cast<int>((*max - *min) * ThreshholdPercentageLow + *min);

    // Initiliaze with lowest possible value, so that any other value will be bigger
    int maxPeak{ std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    // Indexof the max peak value
    size_t maxPeakIndex{};

    // We need to kno, if the search is active
    // And we need toknow, when there is a transition from active to inactive
    bool searchActive{};
    bool oldSearchActive{};

    // Go through all values
    for (size_t index{}; index < values.size(); ++index) {

        // Check,if values are above threshold, then switch on search mode
        if (not searchActive) {
            if (values[index] > threasholdMaxHigh) 
                searchActive = true;
        }
        else {
            // Else, if value is lower than lower threshold, then switch of search mode formaxpeak
            if (values[index] < threasholdMaxLow) 
                searchActive = false;
        }
        // If the search is active, then find the max peak
        if (searchActive)
            if (values[index] > maxPeak) {
                maxPeak = values[index];
                maxPeakIndex = index;
            }
        // Check fora transition from active to inactive. In that very moment, store the previosuly found values
        if ((not searchActive and oldSearchActive) or (index == values.size()-1)) {
            peaks.push_back({ maxPeakIndex, maxPeak });
            maxPeak = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
            maxPeakIndex = 0;
        }
        // Rememberfor next round
        oldSearchActive = searchActive;
        searchActive = values[index] > threasholdMaxHigh;
    }
    return;
}
// Shifts the phase to the left or right
void WaveForm::shiftPhase(int delta) {
    // Shift to right?
    if (delta > 0) {
        // insert 0-elements at the beginning
        values.insert(values.begin(), delta, 0);
    }
    else if (delta < 0) {
        //delete "delta" number of elements from the beginning
        values.erase(values.begin(), values.begin() - delta);
    }
    // Correct time stampps
    timestamp1 += delta;
    timestamp2 += delta;
}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Collection of wafe forms and some helper functions
struct WaveFormData {
    // Collection
    std::vector<WaveForm> waveForms{};

    // Calculate a phase delta. Oriented on the first and rightmost perk value
    int calculatPhaseDelta();

    // Align all wave forms in the collection
    void align(); 

    // Simple input function. Call extractor of upper class
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, WaveFormData& wfd) {
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<WaveForm>(is), {}, std::back_inserter(wfd.waveForms));
        return is;
    }
    // And simple output. Use upper class to do the work
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const WaveFormData& wfd) {
        std::copy(wfd.waveForms.begin(), wfd.waveForms.end(), std::ostream_iterator<WaveForm>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};
// Over all waveforms in the collection, get right most first peak value
int WaveFormData::calculatPhaseDelta() {

    int rightMostPeakIndex{ std::numeric_limits<int>::min() };
    for (auto& wf : waveForms) {
        wf.findPeaks(); // Calculate the peaks
        if (not wf.peaks.empty())
            // Get first peak rightmost peak. So, the peak in a first cycle
            rightMostPeakIndex = std::max(rightMostPeakIndex, static_cast<int>(wf.peaks[0].first));
    }
    return rightMostPeakIndex;
}

// Shift all values in a way that max peak values are aligned
void WaveFormData::align() {

    int delta = calculatPhaseDelta();
    for (auto& wf : waveForms) {
        if (not wf.peaks.empty()) {

            // Shift phase
            wf.shiftPhase(delta - static_cast<int>(wf.peaks[0].first));

            // Recalculate new positions
            wf.findPeaks();
        }
    }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This will contain 2 set of wafe forms that will be aligned
struct AlignedWaveForms {
    AlignedWaveForms(const WaveFormData& wfd1, const WaveFormData& wfd2) : wafeFormData1(wfd1), wafeFormData2(wfd2) { align(); }
    WaveFormData wafeFormData1{};
    WaveFormData wafeFormData2{};

    void align();

    // Simple output functrions, reuse upperclassesinserter operations
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const AlignedWaveForms& awf) {
        return os << awf.wafeFormData1 << "\n\n" << awf.wafeFormData2 << "\n\n";;
    }
};
// Do the alignment and phase shift for 2 collections of wafe forms
void AlignedWaveForms::align() {
    // Get phase shift delta for all curves
    int delta = std::max(wafeFormData1.calculatPhaseDelta(), wafeFormData2.calculatPhaseDelta());
    // Shift the phase for wave form 1
    for (auto& wf : wafeFormData1.waveForms) {
        if (not wf.peaks.empty()) {
            wf.shiftPhase(delta - static_cast<int>(wf.peaks[0].first));
            wf.findPeaks();
        }
    }
    // Shift the phase for wave form 2
    for (auto& wf : wafeFormData2.waveForms) {
        if (not wf.peaks.empty()) {
            wf.shiftPhase(delta - static_cast<int>(wf.peaks[0].first));
            wf.findPeaks();
        }
    }
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


const std::array<std::string, 2> fileNames{{ std::string("r:\\data1.txt"),std::string("r:\\data2.txt") }};
void createTestData();

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
    // createTestData();

    if (std::ifstream fileStream1{ fileNames[0] }, fileStream2{ fileNames[1] }; fileStream1 && fileStream2) {

        WaveFormData wfd1{}, wfd2{};

        // Read andparse complete CSV file s
        fileStream1 >> wfd1;
        fileStream2 >> wfd2;

        AlignedWaveForms awf(wfd1, wfd2);
        std::cout << awf;
    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Could not open input files\n";
    return 0;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void createTestData() {
    constexpr int PeakNoise{ 3 };
    constexpr int StandardXOffset{ 0 };
    constexpr double XOffsetRange{ 45.0 };
    constexpr size_t BasicNumberOfRows{ 25 };
    constexpr size_t RowDistribution{ 5 };
    constexpr size_t BasicNumberOfColumns{ 250 };
    constexpr size_t ColumnDistribution{ 5 };
    constexpr double MaxAmplitude{ 100.0 };
    constexpr double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    constexpr int StepWith{ 5 };
    constexpr long SomeTimeStamp{ 100'000'000 };

    std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()

    std::normal_distribution<> xStartDistribution{ StandardXOffset };
    std::normal_distribution<> xNoiseDistribution{ StandardXOffset, 2 };

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> rowNumberDistribution(BasicNumberOfRows - RowDistribution, BasicNumberOfRows + RowDistribution);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> columnNumberDistribution(BasicNumberOfColumns - ColumnDistribution, BasicNumberOfColumns + ColumnDistribution);


    for (const std::string& fileName : fileNames) {
        if (std::ofstream fileStream{ fileName }; fileStream) {
            const size_t numberOfRows = rowNumberDistribution(gen);

            for (size_t row{}; row < numberOfRows; ++row) {
                double start = xStartDistribution(gen) * XOffsetRange;
                int xStartValue{ static_cast<int>(start) };
                size_t numberOfColumns{ static_cast<size_t>(columnNumberDistribution(gen)) };

                fileStream << SomeTimeStamp + xStartValue << ", " << SomeTimeStamp + xStartValue + numberOfColumns;

                for (size_t column{}; column < numberOfColumns; ++column) {
                    const int value{ static_cast<int>(std::sin(xStartValue * pi / 180.0) * MaxAmplitude) };
                    fileStream << ", " << value;
                    xStartValue += StepWith;
                }
                fileStream << '\n';
            }
            fileStream.close();
        }
        else std::cerr << "\nError: Could not open file '" << fileName << "'\n";
    }
}
```